# How to make screenshot of a canvas keeping the current css style ? - Angular / javascript

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, angular6, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of the following canvas:

```
<div class="A">
    <canvas width="700" height="500" style="filter: brightness(200%)"></canvas>
<div class="A">
```

I have the following method:

```
    takeSnapshot() {
    const canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('A')[0].childNodes[0] as HTMLCanvasElement;
    console.log(canvas);
    const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('png');
    const link = document.getElementsByClassName('link')[0];
    link.setAttribute('download', 'snapshot-' + this.convertTimeStamp(Date.now()) + '.png');
    link.setAttribute('href', dataUrl.replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream'));
    link.click();
  }
```

But the style `style="filter: brightness(200%)"` is not keepling on the png dowloaded image. How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

### Filter canvas pixels

The filter applied by the canvas style does not effect the pixels held by the canvas. This style is applied while compositing the canvas with the rest of the page.

To change the pixels on the canvas you need to set [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) property and then render what you want the filter applied to.

- **Note** that `filter` is experimental so check support.
- **Note** that some filters will taint the canvas and thus not let you access the pixels, `toDataURL` will throw an error and you will not be able to download the canvas.

  This does not apply to the standard named CSS filters like functions  `blur()`, `brightness()`, `contrast()`, `drop-shadow()`, `grayscale()`, `hue-rotate()`, `invert()`, `opacity()`, `saturate()`, and `sepia()`

### Example

Applying brightness filter before downloading canvas content.

```
takeSnapshot() {
    const canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('A')[0].childNodes[0];    
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Set important canvas state to defaults
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

    // Set the filter function
    ctx.filter = "brightness(200%)";

    // Make sure all pixels are completely replaced. Important if there are transparent pixels
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";

    // Copy canvas to itself applying the filter as it does so.
    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

    // Turn off filter
    ctx.filter = "none";

    // Restore default comp op
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    
    // Download
    const link = document.getElementsByClassName('link')[0];
    link.download = 'snapshot-' + this.convertTimeStamp(Date.now()) + '.png';
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL('png').replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');
    link.click();
}
```

**Note** This requires the [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D). If the canvas content was created using another API you will not be able to get a 2d context. You thus need to create a temp canvas, the same size and draw the old canvas onto the new one (using the same method as in the example above) then download the new canvas.

### If [`canvas.getContext("2d")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) returns null

As I don't know how your canvas was rendered the more robust version of the function checks to see if a 2D context can be obtained, if not then copy (using filter) to a new canvas and save that.

```
takeSnapshot() {
    var dlCanvas, ctx;
    const can = document.getElementsByClassName('A')[0].childNodes[0];  
    ctx = can.getContext("2d"); // ctx may be null (eg the canvas was rendered using webGL

    if (!ctx) { // failed to get 2D API create a second canvas to apply the filter
        dlCanvas = Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"), {
             width: can.width, height: can.height
        });
        ctx = dlCanvas.getContext("2d");
    } else {
        dlCanvas = can;
    }

    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.filter = "brightness(200%)";
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
    ctx.drawImage(can, 0, 0);
    ctx.filter = "none";
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    
    const link = document.getElementsByClassName('link')[0];
    link.download = 'snapshot-' + this.convertTimeStamp(Date.now()) + '.png';
    link.href = dlCanvas.toDataURL('png').replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');
    link.click();
}
```